# Failed to build a React Native signed release

Tags: android, gradle, react-native

I'm working on a react-native app and when i try to build a signed release i get this error:

> **Task :app:mergeDexRelease FAILED**
>   AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"Type com.BV.LinearGradient.BuildConfig
>   is defined multiple times:
>   /node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android/build/.transforms/aaad2255142356c3377f56df42cfb484/classes/classes.dex,
>   /android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/out/classes.dex","sources":[{"file":"/node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android/build/.transforms/aaad2255142356c3377f56df42cfb484/classes/classes.dex"}],"tool":"D8"}
>   com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Error while
>   merging dex archives:  Type com.BV.LinearGradient.BuildConfig is
>   defined multiple times:
>   /node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android/build/.transforms/aaad2255142356c3377f56df42cfb484/classes/classes.dex,
>   /android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/out/classes.dex
>   Learn how to resolve the issue at
>   https://developer.android.com/studio/build/dependencies#duplicate_classes.
>     at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.getExceptionToRethrow(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:132)
>     at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:119)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.transforms.DexMergerTransformCallable.call(DexMergerTransformCallable.java:102)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.DexMergingTaskRunnable.run(DexMergingTask.kt:445)
>     at
>   com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade.run(Workers.kt:348)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AdapterWorkAction.execute(AdapterWorkAction.java:50)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:47)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:65)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:98)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:61)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:416)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:406)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:165)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:250)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:158)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:102)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.operations.DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.call(DelegatingBuildOperationExecutor.java:36)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:56)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:215)
>     at
>   org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor$3.call(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:210)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:215)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:164)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:131)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>     at
>   org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
>   com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to
>   complete  at com.android.tools.r8.utils.O.a(:65)  at
>   com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(:11)  at
>   com.android.builder.dexing.D8DexArchiveMerger.mergeDexArchives(D8DexArchiveMerger.java:117)
>     ... 34 more Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Error:
>   /node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android/build/.transforms/aaad2255142356c3377f56df42cfb484/classes/classes.dex,
>   Type com.BV.LinearGradient.BuildConfig is defined multiple times:
>   /node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android/build/.transforms/aaad2255142356c3377f56df42cfb484/classes/classes.dex,
>   /android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/out/classes.dex
>     at com.android.tools.r8.utils.y0.a(:21)     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.x0.a(:30)  at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.x0.a(:10)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1990)
>     at com.android.tools.r8.utils.x0.a(:6)  at
>   com.android.tools.r8.graph.A0$c.a(:6)     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(:85)     at
>   com.android.tools.r8.dex.a.a(:12)     at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(:6)
>     at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(:1)    at
>   com.android.tools.r8.utils.O.a(:30)   ... 36 more Caused by:
>   com.android.tools.r8.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed to
>   complete Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.b: Error:
>   /node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android/build/.transforms/aaad2255142356c3377f56df42cfb484/classes/classes.dex,
>   Type com.BV.LinearGradient.BuildConfig is defined multiple times:
>   /node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient/android/build/.transforms/aaad2255142356c3377f56df42cfb484/classes/classes.dex,
>   /android/app/build/intermediates/external_libs_dex/release/out/classes.dex
>
> ps:    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"    minSdkVersion = 21
>   compileSdkVersion = 28    targetSdkVersion = 28    supportLibVersion =
>   "28.0.0"

Comment: check you module you are using same module multiple time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve it, i changed the packages' names of the modules that caused problems for me.

Comment: would you mind giving more description which packages names you've changed?