# Failed build React Native app:mergeDexRelease

Tags: android, react-native, gradle

Debug version is compiling just fine, however release fails on task app:mergeDexRelease.

1. I tried so far excluding group in gradle, but without success.
2. I checked also this [Failed to build a React Native signed release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62279758/failed-to-build-a-react-native-signed-release/62302274#62302274) but there is no direct answer to how to solve the problem.
3. I cleaned gradle cache, build folder, removed node_modules and yarn.lock and reinstaled everything
4. I tried to restart pc

The same error appears for 3 packages: react-native-screens, react-native-safe-area-context, react-native-gesture-handler

````
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.internal.a: Type com.facebook.react.viewmanagers.RNGestureHandlerButtonManagerDelegate is defined multiple times: /Users/user/Projects/app/android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/facebook/react/viewmanagers/RNGestureHandlerButtonManagerDelegate.dex, /Users/user/Projects/app/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/build/.transforms/8bd7a67ad8066031ac26f199a2fda1a8/transformed/classes/classes.dex
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.tQ.a(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:14)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.tQ.a(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:22)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.xK.b(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:7)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.xK.a(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:23)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.xK.a(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:10)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2048)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.xK.a(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:6)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.z2$a.e(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:4)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:105)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.b.a(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:28)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.a(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:26)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.d(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:593)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.b(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:1)
    at com.android.tools.r8.internal.ci.a(R8_3.2.47_ebadcf1df6fbed6005a238b8399b2cd411e753b60758261060e399f9498872a5:24)
    ... 36 more ```
````

Answer (score 6):

Answering to myself, the key was to remove
`apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"`
from `app/build gradle`.
I also removed `react {}` block from `app/build.gradle`.

Can be closed.

Comment: This actually worked. Now I'm confused how the core "react" plugin could be causing an issue in a react native application. Even more confused how anything still works after removing it.

Answer (score 1):

As the error indicate, then the class `com.facebook.react.viewmanagers.RNGestureHandlerButtonManagerDelegate` is defined multiple times. From what I can see it is defined both in the app itself (`/Users/user/Projects/app/android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/facebook/react/viewmanagers/RNGestureHandlerButtonManagerDelegate.dex`) and in a module (`/Users/user/Projects/app/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/build/.transforms/8bd7a67ad8066031ac26f199a2fda1a8/transformed/classes/classes.dex`). You will have to ensure that there are not two definitions.

The reason this works in debug mode is that the build of the app does not do a full merge of the DEX flies, but just copies in a number of DEX files into the debug APK.

For D8/R8 reference the retrced stacktrace is

```
Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.utils.AbortException: Type com.facebook.react.viewmanagers.RNGestureHandlerButtonManagerDelegate is defined multiple times: /Users/user/Projects/app/android/app/build/intermediates/project_dex_archive/release/out/com/facebook/react/viewmanagers/RNGestureHandlerButtonManagerDelegate.dex, /Users/user/Projects/app/node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android/build/.transforms/8bd7a67ad8066031ac26f199a2fda1a8/transformed/classes/classes.dex
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.handleDiagnostic(Reporter.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.Reporter.fatalError(Reporter.java:127)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.reportDuplicateTypes(ProgramClassCollection.java:74)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$defaultConflictResolver$1(ProgramClassCollection.java:68)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:28)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:2048)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:27)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:266)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:184)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:134)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:104)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.readApp(D8.java:177)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.run(D8.java:201)
    at com.android.tools.r8.D8.lambda$run$1(D8.java:126)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ExceptionUtils.withCompilationHandler(ExceptionUtils.java:80)
```

Comment: Well, I understand the answer, but there is only one dependency like that. I even tried to rename all of the packages, but after 4 mentioned here, new appeared. I don't think it is a problem.

Comment: how to fix this? can you help?